# Where to call Backbone.history.start()?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have read many blogs and tutorials about Backbone and Backbone-Marionette. In some blogs the author is starting the history i.e, `Backbone.history.start()`  in the App '`initialize`'              event, some in App '`initialize:after`' event, some in App '`start`' event and others in the router '`initialize`' event. Well they are working perfectly everywhere.

But still can anyone please help me in explaining, which will be the best way to call `Backbone.history.start()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The surest way is to use `initialize:after`, because it will start the history after all initializers have been run (as the name implies). Since routers will typically be declared in `initialize` functions, this means that by the time the hitory is started, all routers are ready and listening for routing events.

If you simply use an initializer or `start` you run the risk of starting the history (and attempting to trigger a route) before the associated router is ready to process that route.

In the cases you saw, it usually works becasue only one router is involved. But the `initialize:after` method works in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

There is no best way. Since it's a 'start and forget it' method and you won't be accessing it again, it doesn't make a difference where you put it (as in any of the above methods) as long is it gets initiated in your application. This one is all about style.

Comment: Sort-of. You should start it after your routers have been created.